# Невозможно установить SpiDev на OS X

Tags: python

Пытаюсь установить `spidev` на OS X при помощи `sudo pip install spidev`

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
sudo pip install spidev
The directory '/Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/username/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting spidev
  Downloading spidev-3.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: spidev
  Running setup.py install for spidev ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-X8OufL/spidev/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-u6yhj6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'spidev' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c spidev_module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/spidev_module.o
    spidev_module.c:25:10: fatal error: 'linux/spi/spidev.h' file not found
    #include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-X8OufL/spidev/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-u6yhj6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-X8OufL/spidev/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет заголовочных файлов, не получается скомпилировать пакет. Нужные файлы есть в python-dev:

```
# python 2
brew install python-dev

# python 3
brew install python3-dev
```

Comment: да в последние время, все что связано с питонов не хочет ставится.. даже через IDE... нужно её переустановить.

Comment: а так - `brew install python-dev`; `brew install python3-dev`

Comment: @Insider и что, не помогло `brew install python-dev`?

Comment: неа, что-то у меня не так с самой осью..

Comment: *Блин, макось же* — тот самый случай, когда надо бы поставить «минус», но рука не поднимается нарушить полугодовую традицию.

Comment: Что за традиция?

Comment: @Insider что у вас в переменной PATH?

Comment: @Insider наверное это был намёк на то, что ответ плохой и надо бы поставить минус, но обычно Александр ставит плюсы. )